# Azure App Service Remote Debugging Security

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging, azure-security

I want to debug remotely Azure App Service using Visual Studio. I'm going to allow ports 4022,4023 on my firewall.

But is the communication on these ports encrypted? Any evidence?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and see for yourself, no need to trust the Internet with that answer.

Comment: Well, I need to document it somehow to our IT departement and I would also like some official statement from microsoft. BTW, this was comment, not an answer

Comment: Microsoft is not going to be liable if they say "it's secure" in public facing documentation. But you will be in front of your IT head. Just the economics of dealing with this crap for years..